# How to achieve "INSERT IGNORE" using PRESTO

Tags: hive, insert, presto

So in my MYSQL you can use the INSERT IGNORE syntax when doing an insert to rather than throw an error on insert of a duplicate row rather just ignore that row

I would like to achieve the same in Presto working on a Hive database if possible?

I know hive is not a true relational database in the sense the documentation for the INSERT statement on Presto is very basic

I would just like to know if there is a simple work around as all I can think of is first doing a select with a cursor to loop through results and insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Hive 3, there is no concept of unique constraints and even in Hive 3 the constraints are not enforced to the best of my knowledge.

Therefore Presto Hive connector does not enforce any unique constraints, so your INSERT query will never fail when you insert duplicated rows. They will just be stored as independent copies of data.

If you want to maintain uniqueness, this needs to be handled externally, on the application level.

Comment: Hmmmm. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the error I am getting then : Query 20191024_134009_00671_tux4k failed: Cannot insert into existing partition of bucketed Hive table year_week_of_year=2012020000.    This query runs fine the first time when the data does not exist  but fails the second time once that data was inserted the first time round

Comment: @MarkZA starting with Presto 318, Presto (correctly) allows inserts into existing partitions of bucketed tables. Please download the latest version from https://prestosql.io/download.html.

Comment: Thanks will do so. Just a question though, if it inserts the same data twice when I do a select statement will I get 2 identical rows?. I have tired using the OVERWRITE statement but PRESTO keeps giving me a syntax error on this? Still trying to wrap my head around the whole hadoop thing coming from a traditional relational database backgorund

Comment: You probably want `insert_existing_partitions_behavior`. See documentation task https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/485 for more information.

Comment: Piotr Findeisen you are my hero thanks. Upgraded to .204 for now as that is where insert_existing_partitions_behavior was introduced. Set the property to overwrite and now my query runs as many times as I like without errors. Had a bit of hassles upgrading to .204 with the max_memory_per_node requirements but once that was sorted all was good. Thank You

Comment: @MarkZA thanks. Please mark this as accepted so that SO doesn't list the question as "unanswered". BTW I recommend that you upgrade to Presto 323. There is a ton of improvements since .204.

Comment: Hi. I have a related question. How can I set the "insert_existing_partitions_behavior" Session Property to persist though presto queries, or even rather change the default value to be "OVERWRITE". I came across this in the Presto documentation : [link]https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/admin/session-property-managers.html but cant seem to get it working. I created the properties and json files and put them in the etc folder on the presto node server but presto does not seem to read this when I create a new session and do a query?